# How to render and save dynamic properties of a Backbone Model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am totally lost on how to implement a solution for the following problem:

I have a Backbone View that is populated with the properties from a Backbone Model. In this view, the attributes are displayed and for one of the attributes, the user needs to be able to add or modify the existing ones. This would be best suited to be an array of properties within the Backbone Model (I think).

I have added a test case in the [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Njy/)

As you can see in the fiddle, the dog's `favorite_snacks` can be added to by the user, but I have been completely struggling on how to write the code to parse and render this in upon instantiating the view and then save them back to the mysql database successfully.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this, I've been banging my head against my desk all weekend trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a better idea make sure that views and models behave independently and completely decoupled so that your code can be managed at a later time.

So in this case each Pet can have one or many favorite snacks. So basically you are expecting a **collection of snacks** here and not a **single snack model.**

So it is better to create a separate Snacks Collection and then a `Snack Model`. Then maintain a separate view for `SnackListItem` and then iterate over the List of `SnackCollection` and render the view for each item..

So create separate templates for both of them

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="pet-view-template">
    <p> <span><b> Dog Name: </b> </span> <%= name %> </p>
        <p> <span><b> Dog Color: </b></span> <%= color %> </p> 
    <h4> favorite snacks </h4>
    <ul class="snacks-list">
    </ul>
    snack name: <input type="text" class="snack-name" /> 
    cost : <input type="text" class="snack-cost" />    
    <button class="add-snack">add snack</button >
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="snack-view-template">
    <b>snack name:</b> <span> <%=favorite_snacks %> </span> ::
    <b>cost: </b><span> <%= favorite_snack_cost %> </span>

       <b class="toggle-change"> Change </b>
        <span class="modify-fields hide">
             <b class="modify">snack name:</b> <input type="text" class="modify-name" data-key="favorite_snacks" /> 
             <b class="modify">snack cost:</b> <input type="text" class="modify-cost" data-key="favorite_snack_cost" />    
        </span>
</script>
```

I have created a separate view and models for the Snacks collection.  **This can still be optimized.**

**Javascript**

```
// Create a Dog Model
var Dog = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'New dog',
        color: 'color'
    }
});

// Create a collection of dogs
var Dogs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Dog
});

// Create  a model for Snacks
var Snack = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        favorite_snacks: 'bacon',
        favorite_snack_cost: '52'
    }
});

// Create a collection of Snacks
var Snacks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Snack
});

// Define the model for a Dog 
var dog = new Dog({
    name: "Spot",
    color: "white"
});

// Create a View for the Snack Item
var SnackItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    className: 'snacks',
    template: _.template($('#snack-view-template').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        // Need to bind to save the context of this to the view
        _.bind('toggleChange', this);
        // Need to listen to the Model change event and render the view again 
        // as the new data has to be reflected
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change' , this.render);
    },    
    // Assign events for the fields inside Snacks view
    events : {
        'click .toggle-change' : 'toggleChange',
        'change input'         : 'modifyData'
    },
    toggleChange: function() {
        var $change = $('.modify-fields', this.$el);
        $change.hasClass('hide') ? $change.removeClass('hide') : $change.addClass('hide');
    },
    // This will captue the data from the inputs and trigger the change event on the model
    modifyData: function(e) {
        var value = $(e.currentTarget).val(),
            key  = $(e.currentTarget).data('key');
         this.model.set(key,value);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var PetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#foo',
    template: _.template($('#pet-view-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = (this.collection && this.collection instanceof Backbone.Collection) || new Snacks(Snack);
    },
    events: {
        'click .add-snack' : 'addSnack'
    },
    addSnack: function () {
        // Render new snack Item
        var newSnack = new Snack({
            favorite_snacks: $('.snack-name', this.$el).val(),
            favorite_snack_cost: $('.snack-cost', this.$el).val()
        });
        this.renderSnackView(newSnack);
        // Clear the inputs
        $('input', this.$el).val('');
    },
    // render each snack view
    renderSnackView: function (snack) {
        var snackView = new SnackItemView({
            model: snack
        });
        $('.snacks-list', this.$el).append(snackView.el);
        snackView.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var thisView = this;
        // Append the PetView
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        // Iterate over each snack collection of the pet and render that item
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (snack) {
            thisView.renderSnackView(snack);
        });
        return this;
    }
});



var petView = new PetView({
    model: dog
});
petView.render();
```

**[Check the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/VpLUE/4/)**

I have used comments to explain some of the code. It is tough to learn backbone initially as i just started working with it recently and i know the trouble I went thru . but once you get used to it it is very simple yet powerful.. Hope this helps :)

But when you try to build an application , you need to destroy the views and events that are not being used in order to reduce memory leaks.